ERROR while getting api_id and api_hash in Telegram API development tools
api_hash and api_id ​​are used for telethon and pyrogram libraries, etc. to build Userbot using Telegram API and its not the same API that BotFather gives you.
you can get api_hash and api_id from my.telegram.org in API development tools section.
After three weeks of trying and testing IPs from more than 30 different countries, as well as using VPS with Turkish and American servers, I still could not get the api_hash and api_id values ​​for even one of my Telegram accounts.
The phone numbers I used were from Argentina, Estonia, America, and Iran.
My location is Iran and I have used premium VPN servers such as NordVPN, Hotspot Shield, v2ray protocol, as well as VPS in Turkey and America to change the IP.
The browser adblocker has been turned off and it has been tested in 3 browsers: Edge, Chrome, Firefox in Incognito and Normal mode.
Request Data:
App Title: testappnumber12
Short name: testapp12
URL: www.telegram.org
Platform: Android / Desktop
Description: anything / skip

Response:
ERROR

enter image description here
Programmatically requests method | Still gives ERROR
I wrote a simple request code with python and I used session to hold my session and work with that.
I did it because I wanted to use my UK linux VPS with a clean IP.
Telegram keeps returning the ERROR and I think this is a problem on Telegram's side, not a problem on my side. To be sure, can you also try to get the api_hash and api_id guys?
My python code for request to Telegram programmatically:
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def main():

    send_password_url = 'https://my.telegram.org/auth/send_password'

    payload = {
        'phone': PHONE
    }

    response = session.post(url=send_password_url, data=payload)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        if response.text != "Sorry, too many tries. Please try again later." :
            random_hash = response.json()['random_hash']
        else:
            print(response.text)
            return
    else:
        print(f"Unsuccessful request. Status Code: {response.status_code}")
        return

    confirmation_code = input('Enter your confirmation code: ')

    login_url = 'https://my.telegram.org/auth/login'

    payload = {
        'phone': PHONE,
        'random_hash': random_hash,
        'password': confirmation_code
    }

    response = session.post(url=login_url, data=payload)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        if response.text != "Sorry, too many tries. Please try again later." :
            if response.text != "true":
                return
        else:
            print(response.text)
            return
    else:
        print(f"Unsuccessful request. Status Code: {response.status_code}")
        return

    apps_page = session.get('https://my.telegram.org/apps')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(apps_page.text, 'html.parser')
    page_hash = soup.find('input', attrs={'name': 'hash'}).get('value')

    print("hash:", page_hash)

    create_url = "https://my.telegram.org/apps/create"

    payload = {
        'hash': page_hash,
        'app_title': 'testapp12345',
        'app_shortname': 'testapp',
        'app_url': 'localhost',
        'app_platform': 'desktop',
        'app_desc': ''
    }

    response = session.post(url=create_url, data=payload)

    print("Telegram Response:", response.text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    PHONE = int(input('Enter your phone number: (ex. 18880001234) '))
    session = requests.Session()
    main()
    input("Press Enter to exit...")


maybe you should use DevTools in Chrome/Firefox to see if you get some error messages from JavaScript (in tab Console) or there are problems to connect with some url (in tab Network)

There isn't any specific error in Console. actually I saw the code and it's just an alert("ERROR") in case of reject request  from server side.

Why are you using www.telegram.org as your URL for the app? Have you tried with a different URL? If not, can you check with a different URL, maybe?

@HeySreelal good point. As I remember in other APIs they suggest localhost for desktop app.

I tried many things in url input. I saw in some youtube videos that they put www.telegram.org inside url input, so I did same
